# ¿Cómo obtener la diferencia entre dos fechas con hora con JavaScript o JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

Actualmente uso la librería *moment* y puedo obtener la diferencia entre dos fechas, y puedo sacar la hora o minutos por separado, pero quiero obtenerlo en este formato `hh:mm`; por ejemplo la diferencia entre ayer y hoy es de 24:30 min:

```
var fecha1 = moment('2023-05-20 16:00');
var fecha2 = moment('2023-05-21 16:30');
var resultado = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'hours');
```

En este ejemplo muestra la cantidad de horas, que son 24, pero quiero que me retorne esto:

*resultado: 24:30 han pasado.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría obtener los minutos y convertirlos al formato que deseas.

Obtienes los minutos

```
    var resultadoMinutos = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'minutes');
```

Y transformas el resultado al formato que desees.
Acá ocupe para eliminar los posibles decimales

```
Math.trunc()
```

y para obtener los minutos restantes

```
resultadoMinutos % 60
```

Y todo el formateado junto quedaría (agregados los cambios para formato mm y diferencia negativa)

```
        var diferenciaFormateadaMinutos = "";
        var diferenciaFormateadaHoras = Math.trunc(resultadoMinutos /60);
        if( 9 < (Math.abs(resultadoMinutos) % 60) ){
        diferenciaFormateadaMinutos = (Math.abs(resultadoMinutos) % 60);}
         else {diferenciaFormateadaMinutos = "0" + (resultadoMinutos % 60);}
        
         console.log(diferenciaFormateadaHoras + ":" + diferenciaFormateadaMinutos )
```

Y así se vería completo

```
        var fecha1 = moment('2023-05-20 16:00');
        var fecha2 = moment('2023-05-21 16:20');
        var resultadoMinutos = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'minutes');

        var diferenciaFormateadaMinutos = "";
        var diferenciaFormateadaHoras = Math.trunc(resultadoMinutos /60);
        if( 9 < (Math.abs(resultadoMinutos) % 60)  ){
        diferenciaFormateadaMinutos = (Math.abs(resultadoMinutos) % 60);}
         else {diferenciaFormateadaMinutos = "0" + (resultadoMinutos % 60);}
        
         console.log(diferenciaFormateadaHoras + ":" + diferenciaFormateadaMinutos )
```

Ejecutable

```js
        
    var fecha1 = moment('2023-05-20 16:00');
    var fecha2 = moment('2023-05-21 16:20');
    var resultadoMinutos = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'minutes');

    var diferenciaFormateadaMinutos = "";
    var diferenciaFormateadaHoras = Math.trunc(resultadoMinutos /60);
    if( 9 < (Math.abs(resultadoMinutos) % 60) ){
    diferenciaFormateadaMinutos = (Math.abs(resultadoMinutos) % 60);}
     else {diferenciaFormateadaMinutos = "0" + (resultadoMinutos % 60);}
    
     console.log(diferenciaFormateadaHoras + ":" + diferenciaFormateadaMinutos )
```

```html
<script src="https://MomentJS.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Advertir que este código no es conforme al formato `mm`  para los minutos. Es decir, cuando los minutos sean entre `0` y `9`  no imprimirá un `0` a la izquierda como suele ser habitual, sino que imprimirá: `24:0`, `24:1`, `24:2`, etc.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. Modifique el código para que cumpliera con el forma mm de los minutos y que además pudiera manejar la diferencia negativa cuando la segunda fecha es anterior a la primera.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo.

Puedes instalar la librería [`moment-duration-format`](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment-duration-format) que te ayudará a formatear los valores fácilmente, usando los marcadores habituales en muchos lenguajes.

Te recomendaría esta opción, porque es una librería ligera y que se acopla con `moment.js`, la cual ya usas.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var fecha1 = moment('2023-05-20 16:00');
var fecha2 = moment('2023-05-21 16:30');
var hhmm = moment.duration(fecha2.diff(fecha1)).format("HH:mm");
console.log(hhmm)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.3.2/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

---

Si no quieres usar la librería antes mencionada, puedes hacer la conversión mediante las funciones del lenguaje.

En este caso, obtendrías la diferencia entre fechas **en minutos** y luego conviertes esos minutos a horas dividiendo entre `60` y le sumas el módulo para los eventuales minutos restantes.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var fecha1 = moment('2023-05-20 16:00');
var fecha2 = moment('2023-05-21 16:30');
var resultado = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'minutes');
var hhmm = `${Math.floor(resultado / 60)}:${("0"+resultado % 60).slice(-2)}`;
console.log(hhmm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**`("0"+resultado % 60).slice(-2)`** en la parte de los minutos es para forzar un `0` en valores del `0` al `9`.